# Javascript make menu visible only if it's selected

Tags: javascript

I have this menu structure

```
<div id="menu-s">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li>
          <a>
       </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

I use this js:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#menu-s > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#menu-s li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#menu-s li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

i just want to make the sub ul visible when the parent li is called..
Please help me with this..
Thanks

Comment: your markup is all over the place. Sorry.. to clarify, There's an <a> that doesn't need to be there

Comment: well wordpress generates this..

Comment: no, your wordpress theme generates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got an ending tag for the first `<ul>`. Also, your selector is invalid. It should be `$('#menu-s > ul > li > a')`

@edit
Also the code `$(this).attr('class') != 'active'` is invalid because it's always true (I think). You should use something like `if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))`

@edit2
That's because in your if you only handle the situation when the  hasn't the class 'active', but when it does, you've got no code to handle that. Add an else statement that will fix this.

Comment: yes, that was it :):):)
thanks can i add a fade function there.. i mean please how do i do it?

Comment: You're right.. now my issue with this is that i can slide it down, but if i click again on the first li it won't slide up..